# Simplify loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm new in Python and I'm wondering if I can simplify this loop, I need to process more then 100k strings and this takes too many time.
I've read about the list comprehension but I can't figure out how to transform this.

```
result_pos_tagging = nltk.pos_tag(result_ps)
unnecessary_tags = ['CC','DT','EX','IN','MD','PDT','WRB','WP$','WP','WDT','POS']

for r in result_pos_tagging:
        if r[1] in unnecessary_tags:
            result_pos_tagging.remove(r)
```

This is what I tried:

`m_list.append(r for r in result_pos_tagging if r[1] not in unnecessary_tags)`

and this is what I get:

[<generator object process_message.. at 0x00000247198AE648>]

Answer (score 2):

If what you're doing in your for loops is correct then this is the way it can be done using list comprehension

```
m_list = [r for r in result_pos_tagging if r[1] not in unnecessary_tags]
```

[read more about list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

Answer (score 1):

You created a generator expression inside the parenthesis. A generator is a kind of iterator which can contain any number of items.

Use `extend` instead `append` to unpack iterators into your list:

```
a = []
a.extend(range(10))
print(a)
```

**Output:**

> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`